# How to rotate a shape without changing its position in javascript

Tags: javascript, rotation, p5.js

I'm having some trouble with my code. I am creating a little thing for a class where you can draw turkeys on click that bounce around the screen. I have encountered a roadblock in making my turkey however. We did a few examples in class, and now I'm trying to use the different aspects of code to make one final script.

Right now, I will need to rotate 5 ellipses to finish the turkey design, but I am having trouble getting rotate() and translate() to work correctly. While my ellipse is rotated the way I want, it does not appear in same spot depending on where I click to draw the turkey.

If someone could explain to me how to use rotate while keeping the shape where I want relative to the rest of the turkey by the point you draw the turkey, I would very much appreciate it.

Here is my code so far, with the first feather I want to rotate at the very bottom of the script (do note there are some kinks still that I will be working out, but I am just focusing on finishing the turkey before tackling them):

```js
let bubbles = []; //arrayList

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  angleMode(DEGREES);
  speedX = random(1, 3);
  speedY = random(1, 2);
}

function mouseDragged() {
  let a = bubbles.length;
  bubbles.pop(a);
}

function mousePressed() {
  let d = random(10, 50);
  let b = new Bubble(mouseX, mouseY, d);
  bubbles.push(b);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  for (let bubble of bubbles) {
    // bubble.move();
    bubble.show();
  }
}

class Bubble {
  constructor(x, y, d) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.d = d;
    this.speedX = random(1, 10);
    this.speedY = random(1, 10);
    this.d = random(0.5, 1.5);
  }
  move() {
    if (this.x > width || this.x < 0) {
      this.speedX = -this.speedX;
      this.speedX *= 1.05;
      if (this.speedX > 10) this.speedX = 1;
    }
    if (this.y > height || this.y < 0) {
      this.speedY = -this.speedY;
    }
    this.x += this.speedX; //x=x+speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY;
  }
  show() {
    fill(255, 204, 0);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y + 10, 120, 300); //yellow feather

    fill(78, 39, 0);
    ellipse(this.x - 100, this.y + 120, 250, 120); //left dark feather
    ellipse(this.x + 100, this.y + 120, 250, 120); //right dark feather

    fill(153, 102, 51, 255);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y + 95, 185, 185); //body
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 100, 100); //head

    fill(255);
    ellipse(this.x - 20, this.y - 10, 30 * this.d, 30 * this.d); //eye
    ellipse(this.x + 20, this.y - 10, 30 * this.d, 30 * this.d); //eye

    fill(0);
    ellipse(this.x - 17, this.y - 7, 15 * this.d, 15 * this.d); //pupil
    ellipse(this.x + 23, this.y - 7, 15 * this.d, 15 * this.d); //pupil

    fill(255, 0, 0);
    ellipse(this.x - 10, this.y + 40, 20, 40); //gobble
    fill(255, 153, 51);
    triangle(
      this.x,
      this.y + 60,
      this.x - 20,
      this.y + 20,
      this.x + 20,
      this.y + 20
    ); //beak

    triangle(
      this.x - 15,
      this.y + 190,
      this.x - 65,
      this.y + 190,
      this.x - 15,
      this.y + 155
    ); //left foot
    triangle(
      this.x + 15,
      this.y + 190,
      this.x + 65,
      this.y + 190,
      this.x + 15,
      this.y + 155
    ); //right foot

    fill(218, 180, 142);
    // beginShape();
    //   curveVertex(this.x-80, this.y+60); //top of wing
    //   curveVertex(this.x-115, this.y+100);//left side of wing
    //   curveVertex(this.x-115, this.y+170); //bottom of wing
    //   curveVertex(this.x-60, this.y+100); //right side of wing
    // endShape(CLOSE);
    ellipse(this.x - 80, this.y + 90, 55, 120); //left wing
    ellipse(this.x + 80, this.y + 90, 55, 120); //right wing

    push();
    translate(400, -80);
    rotate(45);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y + 10, 120, 300); //yellow feather
    pop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I have already tried using translate() to keep the feather where I want, but I have failed miserably, as I don't think I understand how it really works despite reading the p5js reference and a few tutorials online.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

Ah I have found a solution. By setting the x and y of the feather itself to 0, I could set translate to exactly where I wanted it to be and it now works smoothly :)